# How to determine the sum of the following infinite series problem?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to determine the sum of the following infinite series problem?

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-4)^{n-1}}{9^n}$$

I would get infinity for the following summation and it would diverge, but that isn't the answer.

Comment: It's a geometric series.

Comment: Maybe OP is not familiar with the term geometric series. Basically, it means if the absolute value of the term in your summation, in this case $\frac{4}{9}$, is less than 1, then your series converges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are asked to evaluate $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4^{n-1}}{9^n})$. Note, we can rewrite $-4^{n-1}$ as $-4^{n}\cdot-4^{-1}$. Therefore, we can rewrite the summation as
$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4^{n-1}}{9^n}) = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4^{n} \cdot-4^{-1}}{9^n}) = -4^{-1}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4^{n}}{9^n}) = -\frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n \ \ (*)$$

Now we can almost use the geometric series formula. I hope you heard of it. If not please, look it up. Here is the formula:
$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
It is important to know this. Moreover, notice the summation starts from $n=0$ but our current summation starts from $n=1$. Therefore we need to make changes, and for that we use the property of $0$. Going back to $(*)$:

$$ -\frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n= -\frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} $$
Factoring $\frac{1}{4}$ from the first two terms:
$$-\frac{1}{4}\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = -\frac{1}{4} ( \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n + 1) + \frac{1}{4}$$
Now we use the fact that any (non-zero) numbers to the power of zero is $1$. That means $1 = (\frac{-4}{9})^0$. It follows
$$ -\frac{1}{4} ( \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n + 1) + \frac{1}{4} = -\frac{1}{4} ( \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n + (\frac{-4}{9})^0) + \frac{1}{4} $$
Only now, we can change the index and state
$$ -\frac{1}{4} ( \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n + (\frac{-4}{9})^0) + \frac{1}{4} = -\frac{1}{4} ( \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n) + \frac{1}{4} \ \ (**)$$
Now we are ready to evaluate $ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n $ using the formula I mentioned. It follows 
$$\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{-4}{9}} = \frac{1}{\frac{13}{9}} = \frac{9}{13} $$
Going back to $(**)$
$$ -\frac{1}{4} ( \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-4}{9})^n) + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{-1}{4} \cdot \frac{9}{13} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{13} $$
So the answer to the given summation is $\frac{1}{13}$

$$ \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-4^{n-1}}{9^n}) = \frac{1}{13} $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: as saulspatz suggests,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(-4\right)^{n-1}}{9^{n}}
= \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \sum_n \left(-\frac{4}{9}\right)^{n}
$$

Comment: $-4$ or $-\frac{1}{4}$?